# Fix missing library on FreeBSD

Tags: samba, freebsd

When starting samba on my FreeBSD machine, I get an error that says

```
/libexec/ld-elf.so.1 : Shared object "libgcrypt.so.15" not found, required by "smbd"
```

It is essential to say that I somehow "broke" this while updating some other ports using port manager.

Googling around hasn't helped much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `libgcrypt` was somehow updated you might need to update all the ports that depends on it (samba might be one of them). Try running:

```
portupgrade -rf libgcrypt
portmaster -r libgcrypt
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely, assuming Samba worked before on the host, that updating another port or package replaced `libgcrypt.so.15` with a later version, while the `smbd` binary was linked with that specific version.  Check if you have a `libgcrypt.so` symbolic link pointing to a a different numbered version.

In that case, assuming that the newer version is backward binary compatible, you should be able to to work around this by creating a symbolic link from `libgcrypt.so.15` to the newer version you have.  It is however recommended to rebuild Samba with the newer version instead, in case there are any differences in the include files of the library.

Another possibility is that the package containing `libgcrypt.so` was uninstalled (due to a new conflict dependency or deprecation), but if Samba was installed from a FreeBSD port, this should have issued a warning.